# how to count, how often values from one column have a value in common in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe with guests in tv-talkshows. It kind of looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'guest' : ['Donald','Barack','Hillary','Hillary','Barack','Joe'],
                   'show' : ['Episode1', 'Episode1', 'Episode1', 'Episode2', 'Episode2', 'Episode2']
})

    guest   show
0   Donald  Episode1
1   Barack  Episode1
2   Hillary Episode1
3   Hillary Episode2
4   Barack  Episode2
5   Joe     Episode2
```

Now I'd like to find out, who was invited with whom to the same show most often. So the result should look like this:

```
      Donald Barack Hillary Joe
Donald  1     1       1     0
Barack  1     2       2     1
Hillary 1     2       2     1
Joe     0     1       1     1
```

Alternatively I'd like to find out have those values sorted per each guest, so for Barack it would be:

```
Hillary    2
Barack     2
Joe        1
Donald     1
```

I can't even provide some code I tried that with. I'm pretty lost. Neither `groupby` or the various forms of `melt`, `crosstab` or `pivot` have helped me a lot.

Any suggestions?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=df.merge(df, how='inner', on='show')
result=pd.get_dummies(x.guest_y).groupby(x.guest_x).apply(sum)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! It seems like I'll have to look into `merge` more! I'm excited about the possibilities I have with this dataset :)

Answer (score 0):

First, a self join on the episode will give all the pairs that shared the same episode of the show. Then, by grouping by pairs of guests you can count in how many different shows they were invited together:

```
df.merge( df, on=['show'] ).groupby(['guest_x', 'guest_y']).show.count()
```

Here, `guest_x` and `guest_y` are the names that the columns take by default when performing the self join. In case you want a neat solution, consider making a copy and renaming the columns.

Comment: thanks a lot! It seems I'll have to look into `merge`!